# Why won't my code compile with libpcap?

Tags: c, ubuntu, pcap, libpcap

I am trying to compile the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcap.h>

#define listen_device "eth0"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *dev, errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

    dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf); // err 'pcap_lookupdev undefined'
    if (dev == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't find default device: %s\n", errbuf);
        return(2);
    }
    printf("Device: %s\n", dev);
    return(0);
}
```

Even know my pcap header defines `pcap_lookupdev`:

```
...
char    *pcap_lookupdev(char *);
...
```

I installed libpcap via:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcap0.8-dev
```

Whenever I try to use a function that is declared in the pcap header, gcc gives the error `function is undefined`. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: add `-lpcap` to the end of the compilation line - you're not linking to the library which is needed when you use `libpcap` functions.

Comment: Is it failing during linking, or earlier?

Comment: The **full** and **exact** error message should **always** be posted when you're trying to find the root-cause, please.

Comment: I was trying to compile using crossgcc in eclipse, I posted the console output from compiling using GCC in command line.

Comment: @John you have to move the `-lpcap` to the *end* of the compile line - the linker doesn't know that you need the routine until it's got code that depends on it.

Comment: @Petesh ahh, that was my issue =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to compile libpcap applications under Ubuntu:

1. Install libpcap: `sudo apt-get install libpcap0.8-dev`
2. setup eclipse linker to handle libpcap:

   `Project -> properties -> build settings -> linker -> libraries -> add library`

All you have to do is type in pcap.

To compile from the command line all you have to do is:

```
gcc -o {output} file.c -lpcap
```